# How do I stop recurring error messages from appearing in messages and auditd.log?

Tags: linux, centos, logrotate, auditd

On my CentOS linux machine, in my auditd.conf file, I have set my max_log_file_action=keep_logs.

However, in my /var/log/messages and /var/log/auditd.log, the following message appears multiple times a second which is filling up those log files quickly:

```
Audit daemon rotating log files with keep option 
Last known log disappeared (/data/log/audit.log.5) 
Next log to use will be /data/log/audit.log.5
```

Why are these messages appearing? Why so frequently? And how do I make them go away? they are incorrect nuisance messages (i.e., I'm not trying to rotate my auditd log).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Note that my intent is to have a single log file - and not rotate it.

I also had num_logs set to 1. The spec is if num_logs is less than 2, it will not rotate. With this set to 1, it almost shouldn't matter what max_log_file_action is since there is no rotation. But with that set to "keep_logs" the system kept trying to rotate, and failing, and putting these messages into my messages and auditd.log files.

I set max_log_file_action to 'ignore'.  I am now getting the desired behavior:  single audit log file; no erroneous/extraneous messages in the messages and auditd.log files.